# MSOLEDBSQL Driver installation fails with C#

Tags: c#, windows-installer, oledb

I need to install the MSOLEDBSQL driver (msi file) programmatically, for which I have written the function below :

```
public static void InstallSQLDriver()
        {
            
            string msiPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)+@"\msoledbsql.msi";
            string winDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows);
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Path.Combine(winDir, @"System32\msiexec.exe"), $"/i {msiPath} /quiet /qn /norestart ALLUSERS=1");
            startInfo.Verb = "runas";
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            Process proc = Process.Start(startInfo);
            proc.WaitForExit();
            Console.WriteLine("process ended with : " + proc.ExitCode);
        }
```

This runs fine on the dev machine and exits with status code 0 (success), However, when I run the .exe on another machine, it gives me the exit code 1603. When I look through the eventviewer logs I see an error saying that the IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS=YES parameter is missing. I tried add the parameter in the startInfo variable as below :

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Path.Combine(winDir, @"System32\msiexec.exe"), $"/i {msiPath} /quiet /IAcceptMSOLEDBSQLLicenseTerms/qn /norestart ALLUSERS=1");
```

but this doesn't work and I get the 1639 error code, which says this parameter is invalid.

Can someone please tell me how to include this parameter in my startInfo variable?

Comment: I might be completely off, but don’t you simply need to add =YES in your string?

Comment: oops! that did it. Thank you @LaurentGabiot :)

Comment: Good, now you can write the answer!

Answer (score 0):

This one is pretty simple. The value of the **IAcceptMSOLEDBSQLLicenseTerms** needs to be passed as **YES** in the startInfo string. So the new startInfo variable looks as below :

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Path.Combine(winDir, @"System32\msiexec.exe"), $"/i {msiPath} /quiet IAcceptMSOLEDBSQLLicenseTerms=YES  /qn ACCEPTEULA=1 /norestart ALLUSERS=1");
```

Once this is set, the exe installs the driver without issues.